# Why running pandas in pyodide wasm results in memory error?

Tags: python, pandas, webassembly, pyodide

I was trying pyodide in browser.
When I try a simple pandas, numpy script I'm getting fatal error memory access out of bounds:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Chrome, it's very likely a bug in Chrome 89 - 90, which should be fixed in Chrome 91.

For more details see: [pyodide#1507](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/1507) and [bugs.chromium.org#1200031](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1200031)

Comment: Indeed this was the problem. Solved, I can continue my exploration adventure :-)